# Pandas - Correlation .corr() for int64 datatypes in a datatype returns the same correlation. Bug?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'm trying to find the correlations between a target column with datatype float, and other columns with mixed datatypes.

`df.datatypes`
returns:

```
Pos           object
Age          float64
Year           int64
Pts Won      float64
Pts Max      float64
Share        float64
Team          object
Team Rank    float64
W            float64
L            float64
W/L%         float64
GB            object
PS/G         float64
PA/G         float64
SRS          float64
G TOT        float64
GS TOT       float64
MP TOT       float64
FG TOT       float64
FGA TOT      float64
FG%          float64
3P TOT       float64
3PA TOT      float64
3P%          float64
2P TOT       float64
2PA TOT      float64
2P%          float64
eFG%         float64


dtype: object
```

Here, when I run the pandas correlation command to find correlations with column `Share`, everything returns normal with **unique** correlation values:

```
Age          0.018080
Year        -0.008203
Pts Won      0.995639
Pts Max      0.523850
Share        1.000000
Team Rank   -0.124671
W            0.119965
L           -0.119570
W/L%         0.124102
PS/G         0.041559
PA/G        -0.039062
SRS          0.118732
G TOT        0.089035
GS TOT       0.166717
MP TOT       0.167609
FG TOT       0.285257
FGA TOT      0.258544
FG%          0.063012
3P TOT       0.118244
3PA TOT      0.120624
3P%          0.009359
2P TOT       0.289153
2PA TOT      0.265193
2P%          0.058526
eFG%         0.055817
```

However, when I convert select columns to type `int64` and rerun the correlation, I recieve repeating correlation values for said `int64` type columns:

```
convert_col = ['Age', 'Team Rank', 'W', 'L' 'GB']
for col in df_final:
    if ('TOT' in col) or (col in convert_col):
        df_final[col] = df_final[col].values.astype(np.int64)

df_final.corr()['Share']
```

returns:

```
Age          0.001156
Year        -0.008203
Pts Won      0.995639
Pts Max      0.523850
Share        1.000000
Team Rank    0.004556
W            0.004556
L           -0.119570
W/L%         0.124102
PS/G         0.041559
PA/G        -0.039062
SRS          0.118732
G TOT        0.001156
GS TOT       0.001156
MP TOT       0.001156
FG TOT       0.001156
FGA TOT      0.001156
FG%          0.063012
3P TOT       0.001156
3PA TOT      0.001156
3P%          0.009359
2P TOT       0.001156
2PA TOT      0.001156
2P%          0.058526
eFG%         0.055817
```

As shown, the columns with type `int64` all have correlation of 0.001156 or 0.004556, when this is clearly not the case, both in theory and in back-testing with type `float64`.

Could anybody explain why this is the case and/or if there is a correction? I converted the datatypes to `int64` for user-friendliness / readability purposes.

Samples of data before and after …

Before:

|  | Player | Pos | Age | Year | ... | Share | Team Rank | W | L | W/L% | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13902 | Thaddeus Young | PF | 33.0 | 2022 | ... | 0.001 | 21.0 | 34.0 | 48.0 | 0.415 | ... |
| 13903 | Trae Young | PG | 23.0 | 2022 | ... | 0.05 | 15.0 | 43.0 | 39.0 | 0.524 | ... |
| 13904 | Omer Yurtseven | C | 23.0 | 2022 | ... | 0.0 | 2.0 | 53.0 | 29.0 | 0.646 | ... |

After:

|  | Player | Pos | Age | Year | ... | Share | Team Rank | W | L | W/L% | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13902 | Thaddeus Young | PF | 33 | 2022 | ... | 0.001 | 21 | 34 | 48 | 0.415 | ... |
| 13903 | Trae Young | PG | 23 | 2022 | ... | 0.05 | 15 | 43 | 39 | 0.524 | ... |
| 13904 | Omer Yurtseven | C | 23 | 2022 | ... | 0.0 | 2 | 53 | 29 | 0.646 | ... |

Answer (score 1):

It may be that these columns converted to int64 contain `np.nan`, causing problems with the conversion. For example, in the conversion result below, nan will be converted to a very small number.

```
np.array([1,2,3,np.nan]).astype("int64")
```

`array([1, 2, 3,-9223372036854775808], dtype=int64)`

If you want avoid this, you can replace `np.nan` to `pd.NA`, and use `pd.Int64Dtype` to convert data type.

```
df_final[col] = df_final[col].values.astype(pd.Int64Dtype)
```

Maybe this article will be useful for you:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Unfortunately there are no null values in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the float to int conversion formula to `df_final = df_final.astype({col:'int'})` seems to have fixed the issue. Now I'm getting unique correlation values for `int` types.